# How to use hash value to open a bootstrap modal using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Im using jquery to get the hash value from the URL and then open a modal based on that value. So far my code is:

```
$(function () {
   var activeModal = $('\$\(\'' + location.hash +'\'\)');
   console.log(activeModal);
   activeModal.modal('show');
});
```

But when I run this I get an error that reads: `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $('#modal-name')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `location.hash` is (for example) `#somehash`, then you would want to get the element using:

```
$('#somehash')
```

So why you need the `'\$\(\''` inside?
You can just use:

```
var activeModal = $(location.hash);
```

What your code does is basically

```
 var activeModal = $("$('#modal-name')")
```

Which is not what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem.